# for loop in python with square root condition checkin

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

In C we can check the value "i" less than the square root of n using this for loop

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
```

I have used while loop as:

```
i = 2
while(i * i <= n):
    i+=1
```

Can we able to do using for loop in python?

Comment: Why not? @D_Raja

Comment: then how to check? @Vishnudev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much the same.

In python, typical `for` loop uses `range(start, end, step)` function to get the indexing variable `i`. It loop through `i=start` to `i=end-1` while incrementing `i` by `step`.

```
for i in range(start, end, step):
```

This is equivalent to C/C++/Java's

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i+=step)
```

Then, to stop by the square root of `n`. You simply use what's below:

```
import math
for i in range(2, int((math.sqrt(n))+1):
```

Note that `math.sqrt(n)` gives a `float`. Then wrapping this in `int` takes the `floor` of the `float`. And since `for` loop stops at `end-1`, we add 1 so this imitates the behavior requested by OP, i.e. `i*i <= n`.

Some examples make this easier:
e.g. `n=4`, then:

- `math.sqrt(n)=2.0`,
- `int((math.sqrt(n))=2`,
- `int((math.sqrt(n))+1=3`
  and `for i in range(2, 3)` will run the loop with `i=2` and stop before `i` reaches 3.

Now, if `n` is not perfect square:
e.g. `n=10`,

- `math.sqrt(n)=3.16...`
- `int((math.sqrt(n))=3`,
- `int((math.sqrt(n))+1=4`
  and `for i in range(2, 4)` will run the loop with `i=2` and `i=3` and stop before `i` reaches 4.

While loop is exactly the same. Another way to write `i*i` is `i**2` in python.

```
i=2
while i**2 <= n:
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Its possible as @Tim mentioned, because in python for loop actually traverses through a range of values, but in C/C++ what we have is `initialization;condition;increment` so that exact structure is not followed in python, instead its `for x in range()` so the exact syntactical code is not possible, but you can achieve the same functionality (using while loop also or for loop as shown), as it is based on the features a language provides!

Hope it gives your answer!